# reactjs - update setState with array values

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, setstate

I want to update the setState in realtime but it is giving me hard time since state update is an asynchronous process. May I request for your assistance so I can update state by the time button was clicked.

Here's my code:

```
const [dependentSystems, setdependentSystems] = useState([]);

const getDependentSystems = async() => {
   const response = await axios.get('/GETAPI' + selectedSysID.SYSTEMID)
   console.log("LIST OF DEPENDENT SYSTEM", response.data)
   setdependentSystems(response.data)
}
```

**JSX** part

```
<IconButton>
  <Icon
    onClick={() => selectedSystem(row,'AddDep')}
  />
  <Icon>
<IconButton>
```

**selectedSystem**

```
const [selectedSystemID, setselectedSystemID] = useState('');
let selectedSysID;
const selectedSystem = (row,action) =>{
  selectedsysID = {...selectedSystemID, 'SYSTEMID':row.SYSTEMID}
  getDependentSystems();
  
  (action === 'AddDep') ? openModal() : openOtherModal()
}
```

Here's the result of `console.log`

[image]

I want to save the result of `response.data` in `array` on the first trigger or call of `getDependentSystems` in short in realtime so I can display in modal the dependent system by the time Edit button was clicked. What is happening is I need to close again the modal then edit again to display the dependent systems

Hope you can help me with this. Thank you

Comment: Pls explain more detail ! what want ?

Comment: Can you please elaborate more ? Like what is the prblm you are facing here ? Doesnt `setdependentSystems` updating the state ?

Comment: @MayurVaghasiya I updated the details. I want to save the result of response.data in array on the first trigger or call of getDependentSystems in short in realtime.

Comment: @ShifaT, its updating the state but it's not realtime. I want to save it in `setdependentSystems` on the first call. I also updated the details. Thank you

Comment: it would be better if you can update the question, how you call `getDependentSystems`

Comment: What does "not realtime" mean? What is the "first call"? Please clarify what and how you are using this `getDependentSystems` function, and clarify what the issue is.

Comment: Apologies all for the confusions. This is related my another question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70736363/react-select-ismulti-auto-fill-pre-select-dropdown-from-database-on-first-load

Comment: I updated the codes and my question my apologies everyone.

Comment: "What is happening is I need to close again the modal then edit again to display the dependent systems" sounds like an issue with the modal. Please just include all relevant code you're working and having an issue with.

Comment: @DrewReese hi sir, posted codes were the relevant codes. My issue is on the first load of modal, `getDependentSystems` were called but `setdependentSystems` doesn't have value yet. So I close the modal and edit again to trigger the `getDependentSystems` that's when `setdependentSystems` has a value and display the details in modal. This is due to state update is an asynchronous process. I just want to have display right away the deta in modal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to open the modal and expecting to see the state value you ***just*** enqueued won't ever work, due to the way React asynchronously processed enqueued state updates.

What I suggest then is to place the modal open triggering into a `setTimeout` call so that the function can complete and allow React to process the enqueued state update. Just enough to get the timeout callback to execute on a tick *after* the state update was processed, just about any timeout should be sufficient, but this is a bit hackish and ***obviously*** you will want to fine-tune this specifically to your app.

```
const selectedSystem = (row, action) => {
  selectedsysID = {...selectedSystemID, 'SYSTEMID':row.SYSTEMID}
  getDependentSystems();
  
  setTimeout(() => {
    (action === 'AddDep') ? openModal() : openOtherModal();
  }, 17); // delay by about 1 minimum render cycle
};
```

An alternative would be to store the action in state and use an `useEffect` hook to issue the side-effect up opening the modal.

```
const [savedAction, setSavedAction] = useState();
const [dependentSystems, setDependentSystems] = useState([]);

const getDependentSystems = async (action) => {
  const response = await axios.get('/GETAPI' + selectedSysID.SYSTEMID);
  console.log("LIST OF DEPENDENT SYSTEM", response.data);
  setDependentSystems(response.data);
  setSavedAction(action);
};

useEffect(() => {
  if (savedAction) {
    (action === 'AddDep') ? openModal() : openOtherModal();
    setSavedAction(null);
  }
}, [savedAction]);

const selectedSystem = (row, action) => {
  selectedsysID = {...selectedSystemID, 'SYSTEMID':row.SYSTEMID}
  getDependentSystems(action);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Just stick the *getDependentSystems* as a onClick handler of a button.

```js
    const [dependentSystems, setdependentSystems] = useState([]);

    const getDependentSystems = async () => {
        const response = await axios.get('/GETAPI' + SYSTEMID)
        console.log("LIST OF DEPENDENT SYSTEM", response.data)
        setdependentSystems(response.data)
    }
```

On the **JSX** part:

```js
    return <button onClick={getDependentSystems}>GET SYSTEM</button>
```